# Why set more bits per channel than the screen supports?

Tags: display, graphics-card, display-settings, 3d-graphics, color-depth

AMD CCC has a "preferred color depth" option that has BPC (Bits Per Channel) values of 8 and 10 and 12. I've set it to the least BPC in order to try to increase fps rendering. (I suspect the screen is 8 BPC) because there is no information about this on the manufacturer's website.).

1. What are the benefits of having it set higher than what the screen can show?
2. Maybe for example shaders have better data so they can shade better?

Answer (score 0):

Setting bits per channel higher than the screen can support has no benefit, and Windows only supports 8 bits per channel, anyway, despite whatever the graphics card can support.  I'm not sure about MACs, though.  I understand that MACs are preferred by graphics designers and photographers, so I'm thinking that they can support more than 8 bits per channel.  It is said that the human eye can only distinguish around 10 million colors, so I'm not sure there is a benefit from being able to use anything higher than 8 bits per channel, which yields over 16 million colors [(2^8)^3].

Comment: Can you answer the second question?

Comment: Windows has so-called 32-bit color.  It's actually 24 bits (8 bits per channel [red, green, and blue] times 3) plus an 8-bit transparency channel, which according to what I've been able to read online, is only used for gaming.  So again, there would be no advantage if that channel had greater color depth; Windows couldn't use it anyway.